# Embedding form entries into website

Tags: cognito-forms

I have embedded the Cognito form in our website. Now we have received numerous entries. We don't want manually to copy/paste the data from the entry forms in our web page.

Is there a way we can embed the entries we have received into our website/web page using an embed code?

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely something we have discussed supporting.  I have sponsored the feature on our Trello Board, as I too would like this ability. https://trello.com/c/Qf0BxQEt

Please up-vote and add your comments to the card on how you would be using entry embedding and what particular functions you would like to see in the feature.

For now, there are a couple of ways you can accomplish getting the data into your website, they just take a little bit more work and know-how.

The first is using our "Post JSON data to website" feature. By writing a custom webhook, you would be able to retrieve your entry data and display it on your site. For more information on this method, read our blog post: https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/66/data-integration/webhooks.

The second method would be to use our recently released Zapier integration. Here, again, you can use the Webhook, or many other options that Zapier offers, such as having the data sent to a SQL or MySQL database. Read more about our Zapier integration here: http://blog.cognitoapps.com/connect-your-cognito-forms-to-almost-anything-with-zapier

Comment: I also wanted to get some clarification on something else as well.

The email we receive from Cognito once some one fills the form, which we have embedded in our website. The entry we receive is pure text/html text.

We have an upload button in our form - to upload pictures.

But when we receive the automated email from Cognito it does not show the actual image, it only shows the image file name.

Only when we actually go to the Cognito dashboard we can see the image.

Is there any way we can receive the actual image in the automated email itself?

Comment: The option to attach or link to file uploads in email notifications is a feature that will be released in the near future. It will be part of paid plans which we will also be releasing soon.

If we were to release it as a free feature, we were concerned Cognito Forms could be misused/abused as a free file transfer/sharing service.